# Embedding Vertical Videos in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, video, embed

I tried embedding a vertical video in Wordpress using the following code:

[video width="716" height="960" mp4="example.com/test.mp4" loop="true" autoplay="true" preload="auto"][/video]

Video shows up as 16:9 ratio with black boxes on each side of the video when embedded using the above code. How do I remove the black boxes and make sure the video fills up the column vertically as a 9:16 ratio?

I tried using the below code but the video shows up 16:9 ratio. I don't know why the black boxes appeared on both sides.

[video width="716" height="960" mp4="example.com/test.mp4" loop="true" autoplay="true" preload="auto"][/video]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. To improve your chances of getting a fast Answer, please provide a link to an example demo page showing this video problem. The issue could be one of many things. Most likely... **(1)** Your width/height numbers are creating a bad aspect ratio (so borders appear). **To fix:** Try setting **only one** of either a width or a height number. The browser will auto-correct the other dimension's size to keep a ratio. **(2)** The file's metadata might need to be edited **To fix:** Edit the header bytes of the MP4 (_ie:_ check if a box called `TAPT` exists in MP4 file and edit

Answer (score 0):

You can embed it using the native YouTube block, and adding the following code to the box “Additional CSS class(es)”:

wp-embed-aspect-9-16 wp-has-aspect-ratio

That's not perfect because each time you edit the page, the code returns to 16:9. But it's the best I've found so far.